# Blank output for image subtraction when using raspicam library

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using raspberry pi with raspicam to run a project. I have downloaded the raspicam library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/? 
I am trying to run a code for image subtraction but not getting results. Here is my code

```
raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME, CV_8UC1);
if(!Camera.open())
{
   std::cerr<<"cannot open camera"<<std::endl;
}
Camera.grab();
Camera.retrieve(frame1);
Camera.grab();
Camera.retrieve(frame2);    
Camera.grab();
Camera.retrieve(frame3);
while (True)
  {
    frame1=frame2;
    frame2=frame3;
    Camera.grab();
    Camera.retrieve(frame3);
    absdiff(frame2,frame1,d1);
    imshow("result1",d1);
    absdiff(frame2,frame3,d2);
    imshow("result2",d2);
    }
```

when I run this code I get blank frames of result1 and result2 as output. This is just a part of my code ignore if i have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Well, inside your loop

```
frame1=frame2;
...
absdiff(frame2,frame1,d1);
```

that'll be sort of identically zero...

Also, have you considered the timing here? You're grabbing images very close together in the time-domain, so naturally they'll be mostly identical (bar noise and fast motion) so the difference will be near-zero.

Cheers,

Comment: yeah.. but the same thing works on a windows machine with a webcam

Comment: That doesn't make the code right. Do you actually get nonzero images?

Comment: yea i have checked for the images i have captured.. i guess the problem is with opencv which is automatically converting the result after subtraction into double from 8UC1 format

Comment: i have checked for the difference in d1 and I am getting an output for that